# Mousedown pageX , pageY is not same after mousemove pageX pageY , happens randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a multi select box (click and drag at empty space then will have a blue div ), but the click and drag is inconsistent and i cant find out the problem.

try to drag from a empty space that is around the bottom right , top right or bottom left and you can see that the light blue box didnt actually start from the point where the mouse down

http://jsfiddle.net/wizztjh/jk4Uc/7/

Comment: Is it Okay http://jsfiddle.net/jk4Uc/6/

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Saying it's "inconsistent" isn't very descriptive or very helpful. What are you experiencing (and when) that isn't what you expected or wanted?

Comment: It actually looks quite impressive to me.

Comment: try to drag from a empty space that is around the bottom right cornerand you can see that the light blue box didnt actually start from the point where the mouse down

Comment: @wizztjh I have updated the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code I changed

```
$(this).unbind().bind("mousemove" ,function(e){
```

to

```
$(this).bind("mousemove" ,function(e){
```

The new code can be seen @ http://jsfiddle.net/jk4Uc/6/

**EDIT**

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/jk4Uc/10/ in this your dragging starts exactly from mouse down. I changed `e.pageX` to `e.clientX`.

**EDIT**

This is working precisely as you asked @ http://jsfiddle.net/jk4Uc/11/

Changed

```
var oriX = e.clientX, //<== Here
    oriY= e.clientY;  //<== Here
$("<div id='multiselectbox'></div>")
      .appendTo("#canvas")
      .css({
            top:oriY,  //<== Here
            left:oriX  //<== Here
       });
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: that is I experimenting by adding unbind to it because i suspect that it use the old oriX and oriY.

Comment: Is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: thanks for you help dude! But when drag from around top right of canvas still the width and height is off , i still cant identify the problem